# C++ functions and pointers

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I have an assignment to write a small program that includes using pointers and functions to find square root. I'm getting an error that says "none of the 3 overloads could convert all the argument types" 
thanks for the help in advance

here is the code i have so far. I know it's a mess, I hope you guys can help.

```
void SqrRt(unsigned long int *, unsigned long int *);

int main() {

    unsigned long int number, root;

    cout << "Type in any number greater than 0 to find it's square root: ";
    cin >> number;

    SqrRt(&number, &root);

    return 0;
}

void SqrRt(unsigned long int *num, unsigned long int *rt){

    if (num >= 0)
        rt = sqrt(num);
    else
        cout << "Invalid input! Number should be greater than 0!";
    }
```

Comment: `rt = sqrt(num);` should be `*rt = sqrt(*num);`

Comment: Requesting to use pointers in a program that computes square root is a ridiculous assignment.

Answer (score 2):

`sqrt` can handle only numbers, *not pointers to them*, so everything you'll have to do is to dereference a pointer you're passing to `sqrt`.

What's more, `sqrt` returns a number as well, so you should also dereference the pointer you're assigning to.

Comment: I would suggest passing `num` by value rather than by pointer, and just return the square root via the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite `rt = sqrt(num)` to `*rt = sqrt(*num)`. The problem with your code is that you are not referring to the underlying object i.e, the object the pointer points to. I would suggest you to, if possible to  use references as it is much easier to work with as compared to pointers.